# Adding pointers to vector in loop

Tags: c++

I am slightly confused about the following code

```
void foo() {

  std::list<A*> list;

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
    A a = A(i);
    list.push_back(&a);
  }

  for (Iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); it++) {
     std::cout <<  (*it);
  }
}
```

which prints out three times the object a with constructor argument 2, i.e. the last object constructed in the loop.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That's not how you push into a list. Even if it was - you're pushing references to objects that won't exist outside of the first loop iteration

Comment: @Leeor sorry that was a typo

Comment: Second part still applies - you run over the same object with each iteration, so you have a good chance to see the last value (and that the 3 pointers will be the same), but don't trust undefined behavior

Comment: @Leeor coming from java, I always fall into this trap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a list of dangling pointers.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
    A a = A(i);
    list(&a);
  }
```

In each iteration, this loop creates an object of type `A`, which is immediately destroyed when the iteration completes.  So the contents of the list are undefined.  You would need something like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
    A* a = new A(i);
    list(a);
  }
```

...but don't forget to delete them all in another loop when you're done with the list.

Comment: Or use a `std::shared_ptr<A>` or `std::unique_ptr<A>` instead of a raw pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `a` is local to the first for loop, so it is destroyed at the end of each iteration of the loop. This means that after the loop finishes, all three pointers in `list` point to objects that no longer exist. Dereferencing those pointers causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to worry less about remembering to de-allocate the allocated memory (and have a nicer less error prone code) you should use [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (read about them and shoose whichever fits your needs best).

Here is a small example (notice how the elements in the vector get deleted when the vector goes out of scope):

```
cout<<"Scope begins"<<endl;
{
    vector< unique_ptr<A> > v;
    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i){
        v.push_back(unique_ptr<A>(new A(i)) );
    }
}
cout<<"Scope ends"<<endl;
```

Live demo [here](http://ideone.com/GLIDTK).